# Determining yaw, pitch and roll

Tags: c++, windows

If I look from my screen, x-axis is towards right, y-axis is into the screen and z-axis is upwards.

I have a point(x1, y1, z1) and it is looking at target point(x2, y2, z2). I would like to calculate yaw, pitch and roll in degrees.

I tried calculating rotational matrix and angles but it seems that it is not giving a right result.

Can anyone please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

-swapna

Comment: Two points are not enough to calculate yaw/pitch/roll, as roll wouldn't change either point but only rotate around the line between them.

Comment: Your question is ill-posed. Which order conventions do you want to use? And what do you want the orientation of? Two points do not define an orientation. At least not without more description.

Comment: You can't determine yaw/pitch/roll from just two points. In fact, [you only need two angles to specify a direction in 3D space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system). Yaw/pitch/roll is used to specify orientation, not direction. If you post the code you have so far perhaps we can see what you're actually trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

As interjay commented, two points aren't enough to indicate yaw, pitch, and roll.

You can determine yaw and pitch by first calculating the angle between the vectors < (x2 - x1), (y2 - y1) > and < x1, (y2 - y1) >.  Just use the inverse cosine of the dot product.  Notice that that operation was carried out on the x-y plane, so the next step is calculate the rotation on the y-z plane, or the pitch, using the same method but with the y and z coordinates instead.

I should also point out that you have to be careful about the order in which you apply the rotations.  You might want to consider using quaternions if possible.